# set a public variable in laravel model

Tags: php, oop, laravel, model, structure

Nice Day All,

I'm trying to send a variable to the model to be used in all the function without passing it as a parameter to all function, 
here is what I have do, but it doesn't work, anyone Can figure out the problem?

```
 SomethingController.php
   public function store(){
         $user_value = \Request::input('value');  // get value from user
         $somethingObj = new \App\Something(['user_value' => $user_value ]);
         $somethingObj->doSomething();
   }


 Something.php

  public $value;
  public function __constructor($attributes){
      $this->value = $attributes['user_value']; 
  }
  public function doSomething(){
       if($this->value){   
          // this is not working , $value not working also  $this->$value didn't work too
          doSomething();
       }else{
           doOtherThing();
       }
  }
```

Comment: Does `Something` extend `Eloquent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think passing a value in constructor doesnt work in case of Models. What you can do instead is to create a setter method.

```
    function setValue($val){
        $this->value = $value;
    }
```

Now you can use $this->value to access it in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename __constructor to __construct and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

If your `Something` model extends `Eloquent` you must override static class `create()`, like this:

```
public static function create(array $attributes) 
{        
    $this = parent::create($data);                
    $this->value = $attributes['value'];
    return $this;
}
```

And call it:

```
$somethingObj = \App\Something::create(['user_value' => $user_value ]);
```